# Does Lync Server 2010 Best Practice Analyzer update work?

Tags: lync

When running the update inside the Lync Server 2010 BPA, I get "an error occurred trying to access the web".  I get this from Win7 client or the Lync server, both have full Internet access through router/firewall.  Other BPA's and Windows Update work fine.  Maybe because the tool is so new there are no updates but thought this error was unusually unfriendly.

Comment: Does Fiddler show what requests it's making?

Comment: Fiddler shows now requests attempted.  Network Monitor 3.4 shows attempts to https to www.microsoft.com.  BPA Tool says it's attempting this but URL doesn't exist at MS when I browse to it. https://www.microsoft.com/exchange/code/RtcBPA/LS2010/1.0/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Fiddler and Network Monitor both show that requests are being made to the link you provided above, then I'm going to say that MS hasn't finished everything on their end for that tool to work properly.  I also cannot pull up the link you provided.

Comment: The documentation says that link, but Fiddler shows nothing and I don't have the netmon skills to extract the URL from it's data.

Comment: I installed the BPA and used Wireshark to view the connection.  It's an SSL connection, so the data is encrypted, but I do see it attempting to connect to a Microsoft owned server over port 443 when I try to update the BPA.  Mine also fails.

Comment: Ultimately that's what I was looking for, someone else to try it, thanks.